# Apple pay with amazon payment gateway how to get the token parameter

Tags: amazon-pay, payfort, applepay-web

I'am trying to get all mandatory parameters required to make my request like apple_data,apple_signature,apple_header..etc how can i get these values
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Apple Pay returns encrypted Apple Pay data to you.
2-You will submit the request (APPLE_PAY) to Amazon Payment Services from server side as POST via JSON format including using Amazon Payment Services Parameters.

Comment: you can see this vedio for more information:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-QUR_KZKb0